# Tkinter text widget displaying some characters wrong

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, character-encoding

I am trying to make a notepad application with Tkinter and ran into a problem when opening a file. Characters like "ä", "ö" and "å" show up as "Ã¤" for example.
How can I change the encoding in order to make these characters show up correctly?

```
file = open(self.file, "r")

self.text.insert("1.0", file.read())

file.close()
```

Comment: Please, add your current code as an example.

Comment: Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]. There seems to be a lot of code unrelated to the question being asked. For example, if the question is about inserting unicode characters into a text widget, we don't need all of the menu functions.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with tkinter. What do you see when you do `print(file.read())`? I guess your text file is utf-8 encoded, so you should specify that when opening the file: `file = open(self.file, "r", encoding="utf8")`.

Comment: @fhdrsdg this seemed to be the problem. Thank you!